# Black Screen After boot in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot

I have Raspberry pie 3 with Raspbian, after turn it off and turn on again, after boot (displaying four raspberry), the display shows only a black screen.

I can login with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and access a command line.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

After using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. this should return you back to your normal screen.

If that doesn't work, return to first screen using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then type startx. Enter that and it should reboot normally

Comment: both of alt+ctrl+f7 and startx command not work